# Angular 2 prevent non auth user access route and child

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication

There is the structure of our project:

- AppComponent

  - Nav Component
  - LoginComponent

After the user has authenticated using the form, which calls Firebase, then the user must be redirected to the part only accessible to logged-in users.

- AccountComponent

  - ProfileComponent
  - FilesComponent

As you can see the account component has two childs.

**I'm looking for a proper way to prevent un-auth users to access the protected area of my website** and don't know if I have to call the authService **in a component (appComponent ? AccountComponent? OnInit of one of the component?) OR in the routes definition** with a CanActivate or CanActivateChild ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Use ***CanActivate*** Route Guard.

Assuming your route after user gets authenticated is 
http://localhost:3000/#/dashboard

Here is how you prevent the dashboard route (related to AccountComponent and its child), to be accessed if the user is not authenticated.

**On your route:**

```
{ path: 'dashboard',
    canActivate: [ AuthService ],
    component: AccountComponent,
    children: [
      ProfileComponent,
      FilesComponent
    ]
  }
```

**And implement CanActivate from your authentication service:**

```js
@Injectable()
export class AuthService implements CanActivate {


    isAuthenticated(): boolean{
        // auth logic
    }

    canActivate(): boolean{
        const isAuth = this.isAuthenticated();
        if(!isAuth){
        //if not authenticated do something. e.g redirect to login  page
            this._router.navigate(['','/login'])
        }
        return isAuth;
    }
}
```

Comment: But don't say protect. You do not protect anything on the client side, you only hide. So make sure that, even if the user gets unauthorised access to those components, he won't be able to retrieve any data from the server thus making the pages useless

Comment: @lastWhisper I think that is very obvious. :)

Comment: Unfortunately not

Comment: @lastWhisper BTW I edited my answer to include your comment. protected ==> hide

Comment: @Mehari Don't let to fool you, generally we hide some features of the UI that a user doesn't have access to, but it's related to UI components, not services either client-side or server-side. If you hide a service you should remove endpoint or make it unavailable. Since you are interrupting a service based on authentication logic it's *not* hiding a service. Being used a secure service you *prevent* its usage from unauthorized access.